# how to use interface rather than concrete class to use as DataContext - wpf, autofac

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

I have below concrete class and interference,

```
public interface IMyViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IMyViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get => _people;
        set
        {
            if (value == _people)
                return;

            _people = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person() {Id = 1, Name = "Bob", Age = 45},

        };
    }
}
```

and using autofac for DI,

```
 builder.RegisterType<MyViewModel>().As<IMyViewModel>();
```

Now in my xaml file I am trying to bind a listview,

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Age">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Width="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

In xaml code behind I want to use interface rather than concrete view model class, how to use this?

If I am using `DataContext = _viewModel;` then it's not works and no record bind to listview.

```
 public partial class NetworkConfiguration : Window
{
    private IMyViewModel _viewModel;

    public NetworkConfiguration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //DataContext = new MyViewModel();

        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

    public IMyViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _viewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            DataContext = value;
            _viewModel = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note - if I am using `DataContext = new MyViewModel();` then it's work. how to user interface?

Thanks!

Comment: `DataContext = _viewModel;` is equivalent to `DataContext = null;`. It's unclear why you would expect anything else.

Comment: Then what should be the way?  Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public IMyViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _viewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            DataContext = value;
            _viewModel = value;
        }
    }
```

You need to actually assign the `ViewModel` with the value from your container:

```
      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      builder.RegisterType<MyViewModel>().As<IMyViewModel>();

      // This is your container, here you can get your instances from!
      Container = builder.Build();

      // Create the scope, resolve your interface,
      // use it, then dispose of the scope.
      using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
      {
         // get the vm from the container, assign it as datacontext.
         DataContext = scope.Resolve<IMyViewModel >();

      }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using all the DI code in main `app.xaml.cs` file, the `DataContext` is unknown there?

Comment: Datacontext is specific to a control, so you need to access it from there.

Comment: Yes, Ok. Thanks.